# How to Fix kubernetes proxy request error?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

When the Nginx is trying to connect to API Gateway sometimes I am getting the error like

> [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request
>   //api/v1/ScheduleTimesheet/GetFormHeaderInfo/4803787 from KubStack to
>   http://schedule-cluster-ip-service:60943   (ECONNRESET)
>   (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)

and some times My request is correctly processed

```
GET /servicesDemo/schedule/api/v1/ScheduleTimesheet/GetFormHeaderInfo/4803787
```

I tried changing CPU times and Memory requirements but none of it helps

Comment: Do you have any endpoint for `schedule-cluster-ip-service` ? `kubectl get ep --all-namespaces`

Comment: Yes, I have. Its connecting correctly sometimes

Comment: Is is still an issue?